# Как перезагрузить блок с интервалом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сейчас по клику на ссылку `a` перезагружается информация в блоке с `id="online-comm"`.

Как сделать так, чтобы блок перезагружался каждую минуту?

```
<a onclick="custom_reload('online-comm');return false;">Обновить</a>

<div id="online-comm">......</div>

<script>
function custom_reload(area) {
 ShowLoading();
 $.post(window.location.href, {}, function(d) {
  HideLoading();
  $("#" + area).html($("#" + area, d).html());
 });
 return false;
}
<script>
```

Comment: Желательно в ссылке что нибудь прописать, а script не трогать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавить :

```
<script>
  function custom_reload(area) {
    ShowLoading();
    $.post(window.location.href, {}, function(d) {
      HideLoading();
      $("#" + area).html($("#" + area, d).html());
    });
    return false;
  }
  setInterval(custom_reload, 5000, 'online-comm'); 
<script>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
<script>
  function custom_reload(area) {
      area.innerHTML = 'test';
  }
  setInterval(custom_reload,5000, test); 
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: К ссылке это никак не применить?

Comment: ccылок много у вас или это к одному блоку?

Comment: С интервалов к одному, а по клику с тем скриптом в вопросе несколько блоков

Comment: `setInterval(function(){online_reload('online-comm');},500){
    ShowLoading();
    $.post(window.location.href,{},function(d){
        HideLoading();
        $("#"+'online-comm').html($("#"+'online-comm',d).html());
    });
    return false;
}` Что не правильно

Comment: @steep код в строку смотреть довольно проблематично, поэтому сначала скажите хотябы чего вы от него ожидаете, но на вскидку вы забыли обьявить функцию `online_reload` а вместо нее обьявили какойто непонятный блок кода :)

Comment: ну укажите просто в функии интервала этот блок с id а другие будут так же работать просто оставьте функцию в скрипте, и в setInterval укажите как в ответе

Comment: нее, вам не надо обявлять её в интервале полным ходом, путь она лежит в скрипте и срабатывает на кликах, а в setinterval укажите как в ответе

Comment: Я запутался. Можете изменить ответ на полный скрипт

Comment: изменил, просто в конце добавьте интервал как в ответе

Comment: Добавил но что-то сам не обновляется.

Comment: извиняюсь моя ошибка обновлю ответ

Comment: сейчас работает?

Comment: Нет. Вообще конфликт какой-то

Comment: @steep `online-comm` в последней строчке без кавычек, а надо бы их поставить чтоли

Comment: добавил код в ответ все должно работать

Comment: нет,  там идет переменная с блоком в функцию - без кавычек

Comment: В кавычках работает `setInterval(custom_reload, 5000, 'online-comm');` а что это не правильно?

Comment: функция `custom_reload`  как видно с ее внутренностей должна принимать строку `id` элемента, для того чтобы в дальнейшем использовать эту строку в селекторе

Comment: ааа ну да все логично) это яя не досмотрел вашу функцию извиняюсь

Answer (score 2):

вот както так в ссылке можно сделать, код внутри функции просто вставте свой, я сделал для наглядности, ну и интервал поставте нужный (у меня стоит 500 милисекунд чтобы долго не ждать)

```js
function custom_reload(area) {
  console.log('tik');
}
```

```html
<a onclick="setInterval(function(){
  custom_reload('online-comm');
},500); return false;">Обновить</a>

<div id="online-comm">......</div>
```

Вот еще пример (правда с изменениями в скрипте), который запускает "обновление" 
 блока `online-comm` раз в секунду, а по клику по ссылке идет обновление блока `online-comm2`

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  setInterval(function() {
    custom_reload('online-comm');
  }, 1000);
});

function custom_reload(area) {
  console.log('tik ' + area);
};
```

```html
<a onclick="custom_reload('online-comm2'); return false;">Обновить</a>

<div id="online-comm">......</div>
```

Comment: Нужно без клика

Comment: ну тогда не трогая js не получится :)